# Dynamically add options to a Angular chosen combo box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

The following code doesn't work:

```
<select ui-jq='chosen' ng-model='trainer_list' multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select Multiple Trainers" ng-options='trainer.id as trainer.name for trainer in trainers'>

</select>
```

I took this from an Angular Bootstrap theme, and I'm struggling to use it.  Basically I want to use from this angular script

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/training_system/retrieve_train.php?trainer=Y'
}).success(function (result) {
    $scope.trainers = result;

});
```

and use it in the combo box, i can't use static options, which apparently are the only ones working.  what do i do?

UPDATE:  So I tried the solution by Abhilash using ng-repeat instead of ng-options, and it worked the first few attempts.  But now I could no longer repeat it, and all I have is an empty dropbox.  I didn't change anything, but it's no longer working.   Is it possible that ui-jq is incompatible with AngularJS?

Comment: Apparently the code works... but only after several minutes delay.  How do I get rid of the delay?

Comment: If you want to use ngOptions from a remote with chosen, try using https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<select ui-jq='chosen' ng-model='trainer_list' multiple class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select Multiple Trainers">
    <option value="{{trainer.id}}" ng-repeat="trainer in trainers"> {{trainer.name}} </option>
</select>
```

Debug your variable `trainers`

Just add this code anywhere in your page to debug,

```
<label> To Do: Remove this after testing. Trainer = {{trainers}} </label>
```

And see what are the values in trainer. Is this variable is updating after your server call?

Comment: i don't understand it.  when i debugged the {{trainers}} variable, it showed up in the page, but the select statement still doesn't show the options

Comment: no, wait, it's working!  i reloaded the page and it worked!  thanks for the fix!

Comment: i noticed that the problem is with the delay in populating the element, not the script itself.  how do i get rid of the delay?

Comment: sorry, now the solution is no longer working.  im thinking it's the plugin itself that's incompatible with the Angular script

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it:

In your select tag, put ng-if="trainers". This would prevent DOM loading until your http request is completed