# AngularJS chosen combo box does not load $http.get variables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

So this is related to my previous question here:

[Dynamically add options to a Angular chosen combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917098/dynamically-add-options-to-a-angular-chosen-combo-box)

Basically this:

```
 <select  ui-jq="chosen" ng-model='program_list'  class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="program in programs">{{ program.title }}</option>
</select>
```

doesn't work though I tried ng-repeat and ng-options.   It works if it was static data, but data taken from $http.get doesn't get pushed as options.

I later discovered, however, that: (where a is $scope)

```
a.programs=[{"id":"1","title":"This is a sample"},{"id":"2","title":"Sample Title"}];
```

in my controller pushes to the combo box so finally I realized that the problem is here: (where b is $http)

```
 b.get('http://localhost/training_system/retrieve_train.php?program=Y')
.then(function (result) {
    //a.programs=result.data;
    var prog=[];
    for(var key in result.data){
        prog.push(result.data[key]);

    }
    a.programs=prog;    

    });
```

I've nearly solved it, but I just can't get it to work.  If I alert(a.programs), this leaves a blank notification.  How can I finally solve it?

(BTW, if I write the variable outside the combo box, like:)

```
<label class="form-label" for="field-1">Select Training Program <span ng-repeat='program in programs'>{{program.title}}</span></label>
```

it appears.  Just not inside the combo box.

---This is probably going to get merged with my previous question, I just need to find the solution to it.

Comment: can you inspect the select element and see if the options are there?

Comment: the options arent there. it's mostly chosen combo box structure

Answer (score 0):

It is either the jquery plugin you're using or your rest endpoint. Try to http get from this endpoint and see if it is faster.. `https://httpbin.org/get?item1=Option1&item2=Option2`. You'll need to change your controller code around a bit because that will respond with a different data structure. This should work:

```
$http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?item1=Option1&item2=Option2')
.then(function (result) {
    var prog=[];
    for(var key in result.data.args){
        prog.push(result.data.args[key]);

    }
    $scope.programs = prog;    

});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<h1>Selected item: {{program_list}}</h1>
<select ng-model='program_list'  class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option ng-repeat="program in programs">{{ program }}</option>
</select>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fnf6W8zKK8pYy1SWDh7w) is a plunker to fiddle with. Note that this doesn't use the jquery plugin so if it adds extra functionality my example may not be applicable.

Comment: i tried it and it works... except it doesn't have the ui-jq line.  When I added it, the options no longer appeared.   So it has to be the jquery plugin... it doesn't work with http.get but with static data

Comment: i do need the chosen plugin because the non-multiple dropdown is searchable and i have a large amount of data.  And the multiple dropdown in chosen allows for multiple selections

Comment: Maybe you should use a pure angular multiple dropdown library like [this](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with below:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
$('.chosen').trigger('chosen:updated');
}, 1000);
```